# how to document swagger query parameter with json object input

Tags: json, swagger-2.0, http-request-parameters

How do I define a JSON object value for a request parameter that is `in: query` (not `in: body`)?

Example below:

```
paths:
  /schedules:
    get:
      summary: Gets the list of schedules
      description: |
        The schedules endpoint returns information about the configured schedules.
      parameters:
        - name: filter
          in: query
          description: >
          Returns whether alert runs on matching schedule.


          Example request:


              {
                "type": "a",
                "start" : "b",
                "stop" : "c"
              }
          required: true
          type: string
```

Because it's not `in: body`, I cannot use `schema`.